# PIC assembler to perform arithmetic on 10-bit number spanning 2 registers

Tags: pic, assembly

I wondered if there was any 'clever' way of decrementing a 10-bit value which is stored across 2 registers.  In this case, its the PWM duty cycle value which has its 8 MSB in PWM1DCH and its 2 LSB in PWM1DCL (in bit positions 6 and 7).
I've figured out a way of incrementing the 10-bit value, but the decrementing logic looks as though its going to get very messy.

The code below counts up to the max held by the 10 bits, then switches to the code which decrements the 10 bit value until it is zero.  It's the decrement logic that I'm looking for help with.

```
banksel PWM1DCL
; lsb are in pos 6 and 7 or PWM1DCL register
; copy into W register
movf    PWM1DCL
; or with 00111111 to set all other bits high
xorlw   00111111b
; now increment W Reg and check if its rolled over
addlw   1
btfsc    STATUS,Z
; if zero, then goto increment PWM1DCH
goto    PWM1DCL_HAS_ROLLED_OVER
; store W reg MSBs back in PWM1DCL
andlw   11000000b
movwf   PWM1DCL
goto    leave_incrementing_logic

PWM_HAS_ROLLED_OVER:
clrf    PWM1DCL  ; zero out the low bits
INCFSZ  PWM1DCH ;INCREMENT high register
goto    leave_incrementing_logic
; high order bits have rolled over, so its time to start decrementing
goto    REVERSE_DIRECTION
```

I can see a way of using a brute force method to do this, but its likely someone will have a more elegant way of doing this.  The only criteria is that it must be possible to detect when the 10 bit value has hit zero so that the cycle can be reversed and begin incrementing once more.
The code will be running on a PIC16F1503 processor.

Cheers,
Mike

Comment: Is this your actual code? I see `INCFSZ PWM1DCH` and expected a decrement. It would help to understand if you [edit] your question and provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example, which shows both incrementing and decrementing.

Comment: @thebusybee My code only shows increment. I was looking for guidance on the decrement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment:

```
banksel PWM1DCL
; lsb are in pos 6 and 7 or PWM1DCL register
movlw   01000000b
addwf   PWM1DCL,f
btfsc   STATUS,C
incfsz  PWM1DCH,f
goto    non-rollover code
(rollover code)
```

Decrement:

```
banksel PWM1DCL
; lsb are in pos 6 and 7 or PWM1DCL register
movlw   01000000b
subwf   PWM1DCL,f
btfss   STATUS,C
decfsz  PWM1DCH,f
goto    non-rollover code
(rollover code)
```

Note that in either case, if the `btfsc/btfss` condition is true (no rollover of the LSBs), you go straight to the non-rollover code; otherwise, the `incfsz/decfsz` controls that decision.

Note also that when the "rollover code" is reached, it may need to apply some fix-ups to the values. When the increment rolls over, the value will already be set to zero (not 0xFFC0), and when the decrement rolls over, the value will be 0x00C0. These values might not be suitable for the application.

One way to address this is to apply the above code to "shadow registers" in RAM rather than operating directly on the hardware registers. Then, once any needed fix-ups are done, the shadow values can be copied into the hardware registers.

My main intention here is to demonstrate how it's often better to think in terms of operations on f rather than operations on W in PIC code. It's been a while, but there was a time in my life when I was doing quite a lot of PIC assembly-language coding.

Comment: Dave, Amazingly tight. But the decrement ends up with PWM1DCL as 0xC0, whereas I think it should be 0x00. And PWM1DCH is picket-fenced...should be incremented at the top just once. Haven't tested the INCR.

Comment: @glen_geek: Yes, I'm assuming that the "rollover code" would handle fix-ups like that. Note also that when the increment rolls over, the value is zero and not 0xFFC0, which is probably not quite right for the application either. My main intention was to demonstrate how it's often better to think in terms of operations on f rather than operations on W in PIC code. There was a time in my life when i was doing quite a lot of PIC assembly-language coding.

Comment: @DaveTweed This is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for. You've flipped my thinking around and helped me think of the solution in a new way. I realise there's some tidy up but that's easy for me to do now that the main code is there. Being able to access this kind of experience is what makes belonging to this group so rewarding. Thankyou.